# Fade to white transition between the display of 2 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a transition effect between the moment an image is deleted and a new one is displayed.

I have an image `<img src="..."/>` inside a div, and at some point in my script javascript deletes this image, and replaces it with another. My JS to replace the image is :

```
document.getElementById("avatar-drop").innerHTML = '<img src="/core/script/blueimp/server/php/files/'+file.name+'" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>';
```

And here is what my div with an image looks like :

```css
.avatar {
 width: 152px;
 height: 152px;
 border: 1px solid #888;
 border-radius: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar-drop" class="avatar">
 <img src="https://tracker.moodle.org/secure/attachment/30912/f3.png" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>
</div>
```

I'd like to know if there is way, using JS or CSS, to have a fade to white transition between the old and the new image. I thought about using the css opacity property, but I need the borders of my div to stay visible (only the content/image would fade to white).

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'll try to work something up later to show you - I'm swamped today.  But to get you started... When I needed to do this, I put a white div over the picture viewer that was exactly the same size as the picture viewer.  I hid the white div and during the function that faded out one pic and faded in the next pic, I quicky fadein and then fadeout the white div.  A little noodling with setTimeout and I had it.

Comment: Please put together, and show, enough of your code (think: "[MCVE]") to demonstrate your problem. Ideally create a snippet in your question (that we can easily copy to our answers to solve) or post the code *here*, but link to an external demo (hosted on, for example, [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). The external demos aren't necessary, or mandatory, but they're a definite help. As for the code to reproduce your problem that *is* necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed this looks to be what I'm looking for , and absolutely if you have some time to develop on this later on, don't hesitate ! I'll try on my side, however how do you time the animation so the JS that display the new image occurs right when the div is completely white ? Like FadeToWhite -> DeleteImage -> DisplayNewImage -> FadeToNormal

Comment: Hi David Thomas, the code I posted is, I believe, basically all that is requiered, anything left on my page is unrelated, all the JS part does for now is replacing an HTML element with another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` technique to create this effect. The new image can then be added through the script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('div img').fadeOut("slow", function() {/*fade out old image*/
      $('div').append('<img src="http://placehold.it/500/500"/>'); /*Add image*/
      $('div img').hide().fadeIn("slow");
      $('div img:first-child').remove();/*remove old image now*/
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://tracker.moodle.org/secure/attachment/30912/f3.png" />

</div>
<button id="button">Change Image!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks to be a very clean and simple way to make this work. I'm going to try implementing this right away and update this when done/or if I have some troubles. Thank you !

Comment: No problem! it's the way I would achieve this effect if the image is added dynamically through JS anyway! :)

Comment: Yeah it's very clean, thanks again ! :) I have one small issue tho, In order to keep the image inside the circular div, I am using the border-box css property. However when the first image fades out, it seems to be "breaking" the border-box and the image overflows outside of the circle for the duration of the FadeOut animation. There doesn't seem to be this problem regarding the FadeIn animation, I am guessing the reason might be that the actual html code is added/deleted at the very beginning of the animation. Have you ever dealt with this ? (let me know is this is unclear i will edit)

Comment: @apatik I have added `boxx-sizing:border-box` to my snippet, but cannot reproduce this issue. If you can reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), I'll be more thanhappy to have a look for you!

Comment: You probably should preload the new image before displaying it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle you mean set it to `display:none;`?

Comment: No.  A preloader would help against issues with the script trying to execute the animation before the image is loaded by only executing that code after the image fires a `load` event.  [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/f1kooezs/) demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't preload the image, I should have mentioned that the "new image" is uploaded by the user, and the FadeIn/Out animation occurs when the image is done uploading. That being said I haven't been able to reproduce my problem in the jsfiddle, I'm still working on trying to locate the issue, it looks to be due to a css interaction, I will update with more infos very soon :) Thanks again

Comment: You can always preload.  If you have a URL, you can preload the image first.  Here's a demo of code similar to the above that preloads the image before fading it into view: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/f1kooezs/2/.

Comment: Oh alright, if I can preload then I probably will, I'm afraid heavy pictures would make the animation stutter. Thanks ! @jbutler483 : I found my issue, it's a css interaction happening only on chrome, I will have plenty of time to find a fix for it :) One last issue that fixing the previous unveilled, the FadeIn animation doesn't seem to be happening, or if it is, it's way quicker than on the jsfiddle, do you know if there is a way to slow the FadeIn animation even more so I can check where it comes from ? anyways I'm sticking with this solution, besides this issue it's working great. Thanks

Comment: @apatik you can give the `fadeIn` a parameter that reflects the time. `.fadeIn(1000);` for example

Comment: Great, it's working perfectly, thanks again for your time :) very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can do the opacity technique, but you have to create an intermediate element, so that you don't lose the border on the opacity change:

```
<div id="avatar-drop" class="avatar">
     <div class="avatar-wrapper">
          <img src="https://tracker.moodle.org/secure/attachment/30912/f3.png" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>
     </div>
</div>
```

And then change the opacity on `.avatar-wrapper`

EDIT
demo - https://jsfiddle.net/7ugc6va1/50/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah that seems to be the only was to conserve the borders. However I need to figure out how to make the animation. Thanks !